# How to change Ionic Button text color

Tags: html, css, ionic3

It may be silly question but I am not much familiar with ionic and css, so Can any one tell me how to change text color of the ionic button?

```
<div class="bottom-button" margin text-center>
     <button ion-button color="energized">
       Register
     </button>
</div>
```

Here, Button color is yellow and text color is black. I want to change text color to white.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**fix your code with `style`**

```html
    <div class="bottom-button" margin text-center>
         <button ion-button style="color:red">
           Register
         </button>
    </div>
```

**OR use css:**

```css
button{
color:red
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-button" margin text-center>
     <button ion-button>
       Register
     </button>
</div>
```

Comment: tell for more help

Answer (score 4):

In ionic-4 button text color will be color-contrast which in defined variables.scss file.

you can simple change your button color as well as button text color by creating your own color.

in your .html file

```
<ion-button class="loginButton" color="bgColor"  shape="round" id="loginButton (click)="loginAction()">
```

and in your src -> theme -> variables.scss

```
--ion-color-bgColor: #1c1c1c;
--ion-color-bgColor-rgb: 28, 28, 28;
--ion-color-bgColor-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-bgColor-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
--ion-color-bgColor-shade: #414040;
--ion-color-bgColor-tint: #050404;

  .ion-color-bgColor {
--ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-bgColor) !important;
--ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-bgColor-rgb) !important;
--ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-bgColor-contrast) !important;
--ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-bgColor-contrast-rgb) !important;
--ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-bgColor-shade) !important;
--ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-bgColor-tint) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `ion-button` with color set as primary :

```
<ion-button color="primary">Save</ion-button>
```

change the  following in `theme/variables.scss` :

```
--ion-color-primary-contrast: #edce12;
--ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 237 ,206 ,18;
```

You can also set as secondary, tertiary...

Comment: thanks you saved me some hours :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change color through whole application, then I would suggest you to override text-color variable to your src/theme/variables.scss

```
$button-md-text-color: #ColorCode
$button-ios-text-color: #ColorCode
```

Comment: No, I want it for a single button only.