# Adding a button text color

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4 and I have a button with outline and transparent background. I want to change the color of its text.

According to other answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228206/how-to-change-ionic-button-text-color), the color property is dictate by `--ion-color-contrast` which, however, does not work. According to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634972/how-to-disable-ion-button-shadow-in-ionic-4) answer, I should be able to use `--color` to set it, which also does not work.

The Ionic 4 [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button) says that `--color` should change it but it does not work. Please see 
[link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfzevhsu/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color is being inheriting from --ion-color-base, try removing that by deleting the color="primary" from the HTML, because the .ion-color-primary class is using !important and that property make everything in color.

By removing that attribute, your code will work.

Comment: What you are doing there is that you are changing both the background as well as the font color. I only want the text color.

Comment: Do the buttons by default have the primary background color? In case I want my button to have a secondary background and change its background color then it won't work.

Comment: why did you say that? check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bjnutgh0/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, I wanted to add that I opened an [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20822) and it looks that when theming an Ionic application one can either use the CSS variables or the color property.

Mixing them won't work.